# CoreData relationship confusion

Tags: ios, core-data

Suppose I have two entity named Book and Publisher
1. Book  has attribute :- writer, title. 
2. Publisher has attribute :-  name, type
I set a relationship :- Publisher to Book ( one to many and set it as inverse relation)

With relationship selected I can see in DataModal inspector a row called Delete Rule with three options 1. Nullify 2. Cascade  3. Deny

What these are and I want to delete Publisher entity only if I delete the last Book

Thank You in advance.
I'm just a beginner 
:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs do a good job explaining these delete rules

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/HowManagedObjectsarerelated.html

> Relationship Delete Rules
>
> A relationship's delete rule specifies what should happen if an
>   attempt is made to delete the source object. Note the phrasing if an
>   attempt is made. If a relationship's delete rule is set to Deny, it is
>   possible that the source object will not be deleted. Consider again a
>   department's employees relationship, and the effect of the different
>   delete rules.
>
> Deny If there is at least one object at the relationship destination
>   (employees), do not delete the source object (department).
>
> For example, if you want to remove a department, you must ensure that
>   all the employees in that department are first transferred elsewhere
>   (or fired!); otherwise, the department cannot be deleted.
>
> Nullify Remove the relationship between the objects but do not delete
>   either object.
>
> This only makes sense if the department relationship for an employee
>   is optional, or if you ensure that you set a new department for each
>   of the employees before the next save operation.
>
> Cascade Delete the objects at the destination of the relationship when
>   you delete the source.
>
> For example, if you delete a department, fire all the employees in
>   that department at the same time.
>
> No Action Do nothing to the object at the destination of the
>   relationship.
>
> For example, if you delete a department, leave all the employees as
>   they are, even if they still believe they belong to that department.
>
> It should be clear that the first three of these rules are useful in
>   different circumstances. For any given relationship, it is up to you
>   to choose which is most appropriate, depending on the business logic.
>   It is less obvious why the No Action rule might be of use, because if
>   you use it, it is possible to leave the object graph in an
>   inconsistent state (employees having a relationship to a deleted
>   department).
>
> If you use the No Action rule, it is up to you to ensure that the
>   consistency of the object graph is maintained. You are responsible for
>   setting any inverse relationship to a meaningful value. This may be of
>   benefit in a situation where you have a to-many relationship and there
>   may be a large number of objects at the destination.